# Find the equation of the tangent line in the form $y=mx+c$. Compute $m$ and $c$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

> **Problem**: Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $f(x) = \sin(x) + 3x \cos(x)$ at the point $(\pi, −3\pi)$.

The equation of this tangent line can be written in the form $y = mx + c$. Compute $m$ and $c$.

**Attempt**: To find the slope, differentiate: $f(x) = \sin(x) + 3x \cos(x)$

Apply the product rule only on products which is
$$3x cos(x)$$

$$
m = f '(\pi) = \cos(x) + 3 cos(x) + 3x( -sin(x))
$$
$$
f '(\pi) = cos(\pi) + 3 cos (\pi) + 3(\pi)(-sin(\pi))
$$
$$
= -1 + 3 (-1) + 9.4247(0)
$$
$$
= -1 -3 + 0
$$
$$
m = -4
$$

Then to compute m and c
$$
y = mx + c
$$
$$
-3\pi = -4 (\pi) + c
$$
$$
-3\pi = -4\pi + c
$$
$$
4\pi -3\pi = c
$$
$$
\pi = c
$$

The equation of the tangent line is
$$y = -4x + \pi$$

How am I doing?

**EDITED**

Comment: Two mistakes: 1) missed product rule when differentiating; 2) wrong method to compute the intercept. The given $-3\pi$ is the $y$-value at $x=\pi$, whereas the question asks for the $y$-intercept which is at $x=0$.

Comment: You've omited what is perhaps the most important step: differentiating $f(x)$ to find $f'(x)$, and as mentioned in the previous comment, you didn't calculate this correctly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've identified 3 functions in here and I'm at.

=(cos x)(3x)(cos x) + (sin x)(3)(cos x) + (sin x)(3x)(-sin x)

But I don't know how to continue, do I cancel? do I apply f() now? @BenjaminWang

Comment: The product rule only applies to products. So deal with the two terms $\sin(x)$ and $3x\cos(x)$ separately.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminWang I updated my answer, is that right now?

Comment: Yea it seems right apart from missing some brackets around $-\sin(x)$ but it didn't lead to a mistake. Well done. A nitpick is that technically we have $m=f'(\pi)$, and **not** $m=f'(x)$ for a general $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see your point. I updated the answer. Such a relief. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate $f'(x)=\cos(x)+3\cos(x)-3x \sin(x)$. Then $f'(\pi)=-4$. Therefore equation of the tangent line is $y=-4x+\pi$.

Comment: This is correct. I think it would also be useful for the original questioner if you pointed out why their suggested answer was wrong, and how you fixed it, how you got the value of $c$, etc.

Comment: @MathJack I'm at. =(cos x)(3x)(cos x) + (sin x)(3)(cos x) + (sin x)(3x)(-sin x) But I don't know how to continue, do I cancel? do I apply f() now?